# How to use group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a group by problem with oracle, I'm trying to group together all wards which have service charges over £2500. I have two tables Ward and Bed, wardno is in both tables. Here is what I have and the error I keep getting:

```
SELECT HospitalCode, Ward.WardNo, Bed.WardNo, BedNo, TotalServiceCosts,  
FROM WARD, BED  
GROUP BY TotalServiceCosts >= 2500  

ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Can someone help me with the missing expression?

Comment: If your table names are `WARD` and `BED`, you need to select `WARD.WardNo` not `Ward.WardNo`

Comment: Error! Remove the comma after `TotalServiceCosts`! And you need to use a `HAVING` clause...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for this?

```
SELECT HospitalCode, Ward.WardNo, Bed.WardNo, BedNo, SUM(TotalServiceCosts) AS TotalServiceCosts
FROM WARD, BED  
GROUP BY HospitalCode, Ward.WardNo, Bed.WardNo, BedNo
HAVING SUM(TotalServiceCosts) >= 2500
```

Note: I think you're missing a join condition for WARD and BED.

Comment: This didn't work for some reason, the one below did though. Thanks for your help though much appreciated.

Comment: @jeremy, mine and Praveen Kumar's answers are identical except for me adding an alias for the `TotalServiceCosts` (which is certainly not a problem) and mine being 2 minutes earlier - are you sure this doesn't work?

Comment: @jeremy They posted literally the same answer, except Lucero was two minutes earlier

Answer (score 1):

#### Error! Remove the comma after `TotalServiceCosts`!

You need to change your query as:

```
SELECT HospitalCode, Ward.WardNo, Bed.WardNo, BedNo, SUM(TotalServiceCosts)
FROM WARD, BED
GROUP BY HospitalCode, Ward.WardNo, Bed.WardNo, BedNo
HAVING SUM(TotalServiceCosts) >= 2500
```

Remove the comma after `TotalServiceCosts`! You cannot use a `WHERE` clause here. `HAVING` is an alternate to `WHERE` in case of `GROUP BY`.