# Nonequi joins oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do a nonequi join in oracle to show the staff name, grade and the value of the bonus for staff who have performance grades of B1, B3 and B4.

```
SELECT Name, Grade, BonusPercent,  
  FROM STAFFING, STAFF BONUS, STAFF,  
   WHERE PerformanceGrade = B1, B3, B4;
```

Im having no luck and keep getting errors, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Again you have **no join** between your tables. Have you ever bothered to read the manual? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries006.htm#i2054012

Comment: Looking through your questions you don't seem to have grasped the basics of `join`... I would highly recommend learning the basics of a select statement.

Comment: @jeremy the questions you have been asking are really basic. You should start learning about Oracle basics before starting to post a bunch of questions in SO. Here is a quick short tutorial that will show you the basics http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/377/Others/tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 3):

[Once again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810152/how-to-use-group-by) the error your're getting is because of a trailing comma that should not be there.

Also, `STAFF BONUS` is *not* a valid table name as there is a space in the middle *and* one value cannot be equal to three comma delimited values. You need to use the [`in`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php) function, which is the logical equivalent of 3 ORs.

```
SELECT Name, Grade, BonusPercent   -- NO TRAILING COMMA
  FROM STAFFING, STAFF_BONUS, STAFF -- NO TRAILING COMMA, NO SPACE IN TABLE NAME
 WHERE PerformanceGrade in (B1, B3, B4) -- USE IN
```

However, **and I cannot stress this strongly enough**, the chances of this query being actually what you want is minimal. This will give you the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of all three tables, i.e. for every staff member you get every bonus. Not what you want.

It is more normal to [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_join) tables together using a common column. For instance

```
select staff.name, staff.grade, staff_bonus.bonuspercent
  from staffing 
  join staff
    on staffing.id = staff.staffing_id
  join staff_bonus
    on staff_bonus.id = staff.bonus_id
 where PerformanceGrade in (B1, B3, B4)
```

This is obviously completely made up as I have no idea what your tables look like but should give you a general idea.

I would highly recommend reading up on [joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) and [basic SQL syntax](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/index.php).